# Mvc - Knockout Datepicker binding doesn't work on MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

i am trying to implement too simple Datetime binding with using KnockoutJs and  jqueryUI datetimepicker.

It is working on fiddle, and created a html file and put codes into it , it is also working.Then i created a Asp.Net project with only one html file ,working well.

But on my actual MVC 4 project,it doesn't work.Checked jquery and knockoutJs versions,looks same with jsfiddle.

```
  <label>Y</label>
    <input id="datepick"  data-bind="value: y"/>
   <p><span data-bind="text: y"></span></p>
```

**JS:**

```
  var checkin = $('#datepick').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
  var viewModel=function(){
  var self=this;

  var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    //January is 0! 
    if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd } if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
    today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    self.y = ko.observable(today);
     }
     var VM = new viewModel();  

   ko.applyBindings(VM);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hY5T2/70/)

Mvc  project page :
https://desk.datasel.com.tr/AISDev/Home/Knockout1

Answer (score 0):

Try

Wrap your code in [DOM  Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(function () {
    var checkin = $('#datepick').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        //January is 0! 
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }
        today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
        self.y = ko.observable(today);
    }
    var VM = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
});
```

Comment: Edited code with yours.Still it doesn't update.
https://desk.datasel.com.tr/AISDev/Home/Knockout1

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing. (Using Jquery UI datepicker and Momemt.js)

I have a binding handler. Picked it up somewhere on the internet (can't remember)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var newDate = $(element).datepicker("getDate");
            // newDate format is 2013-01-11T06:11:00.000Z
            observable(moment(newDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    // get the value from the viewmodel and format it for display
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var date = moment(value);
        current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        if (value != null) {
            if (value - current !== 0) {
                date = moment(value);
                $(element).val(date.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Use it like this. `data-bind="datepicker: DueDate"`

```
<input data-bind="datepicker: DueDate" id="DueDate" name="DueDate" type="text">
```

Comment: i dont understand how to use it properly.Shouldn't it contain "DueDate" variable inside js?

Comment: `DueDate` is inside your model. something like `var VM = function(){ var DueDate = ko.observable(); }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem  is just related with MVC as i guessed.
Created new MVC 4 project and put codes on home page,so issue was going on.

on _Layout page  changed all javascript references syntax from :

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js")"></script>
```

**To**

```
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Also on **BundleConfig.cs** created bundle like this:

```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js",
                     "~/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"));
```

Can anyone explain why should i add scripts using "bundles" to use them properly on MVC?
It was just working on single .html file , also works on ASP.NET.

Comment: `Bundling is a feature that makes it easy to combine or bundle multiple files into a single file. Fewer files means fewer HTTP requests and that can improve first page load  performance.` Its not necessary to add scripts using bundles, you can use script tags, bundles are just for improve performace.It seems the problem was something else, may be your script tag sequence was the problem.

Comment: Yes,you are right.As i inspect the order of javascript libraries on loayout page,i see that sequence was :
 1-knockoutJs
 2-jquerycore 
 3-jqueryUI.Then i put knockoutJS to last and problem solved.